# Is it safe to eat ice cream that was left in a refrigerator overnight?

Tags: food-safety, ice-cream

A pint of dairy ice cream was accidentally left in the refrigerator overnight. It was then placed back in the freezer. **Is there any risk in eating it now?**

Comment: Hi, we have stopped answering quetsions of the type "left food X for Y hours at temperature Z", because the combinations are endless, and the answer is always a literal application of a couple of very simple rules. Please see the linked question, and if you wonder "can this apply to my situation, it is too generic" - yes, it does apply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a high risk of frosty and/or hard ice cream. If it's not ice cream, and most of it is actually "frozen dairy dessert", it will likely fare better than real "ice cream".

In either case, it won't be harmful health-wise, as milk and derivatives last several days in refrigeration, so overnight won't hurt. Also keep in mind that overnight is not much time for too many bacteria generations to multiply, especially under refrigeration, so if the ice cream makes you sick, it very likely would have even if it had been frozen the whole time.

Comment: Overnight is plenty of time for bacteria to multiply in some conditions.